# How to push Char** into uin8_t vector?

Tags: c++, vector, buffer

I am working on a function encode data into buffer. I already have functions for the encoding part.

I am encoding and then i push back into a uint8_t vector, which is my output buffer.
For the ints i have no problem, i use my function and everything is done, but now i have to encode a string.

There is already a function made by some developpers before me, which takes as argument char** (buffer to fill), size_t*, and char* which is the string i'm going to encode.

For the char * i just do .c_str() with my string in my C++ object but i don't know what to do about the buffer to fill, because i'm actually using a uint8_t vector.

I thinked about creating a temporary buffer then pushing it in the vector by casting it, is it a good way?

Here is my class (the mother class which is virtual but the string is here so i show you this one):

```
class CDnsMessage
{       
    public:
            CDnsMessage();
            virtual ~CDnsMessage();

            virtual void GetSize() = 0;

            uint32_t       m_ttl; 
            eDnsClass      m_class;
            eDnsType       m_type; 
            std::string    m_domain; 
            uint8_t        m_sizeDnsCorpse; 
            uint8_t        m_sizeDomainName; 
};
```

The encode part:

```
std::vector<uint8_t>& output
char * buffer;
std::size_t* bufsz;
EncodeSmallString(*buffer,*bufsz,RR_A_msg->m_domain.c_str());
output.push_back((uint8_t)buffer)
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you'r trying to achieve, but _"I thinked about creating a temporary buffer then pushing it in the vector by casting it"_ sounds terrible. Actually your "encode part" looks very wrong. Please [edit]  your question and add the prototype of `EncodeSmallString`.

Comment: The code is indeed incorrect. You can not define output as a reference and not set it. Is it not possible to pass output as a reference to your `EncodeSmallString(output)` function?

Answer (score 1):

The encoding part needs to look like

```
char* buffer;
std::size_t bufsz;
EncodeSmallString(&buffer, &bufsize, RR_A_msg->m_domain.c_str());
```

(You pass in the *address* of a buffer pointer and size, and the function will allocate the buffer for you.)

Now you need to copy the temporary buffer into your output.  This is not a cast, this is a matter of copying each byte.  This being C++ there are a zillion ways to do this, but something like:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i<bufsiz;i++) {
    output.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(buffer[i]));
}
```

will work (you could also use `std::copy` or `std::vector::insert`).

Finally, you need to free the temporary buffer.  You will have to look at the documentation of `EncodeSmallString` to see how to do that - the most likely answers are `free` or `delete[]` depending on whether it was allocated with `malloc` or `new []`.

I would be very tempted to rewrite `EncodeSmallString` in terms of appending to a vector, and then write a wrapper overload (with the existing signature) something like:

```
void EncodeSmallString(char** pbuf, std::size_t* pbufsiz, const char* txt) {
    std::vector<uint8_t> temp;
    EncodeSmallString(temp, txt);
    *pbufsiz = temp.size();
    *pbuf = malloc(*pbufsiz);  // or new or whatever the existing code uses.
    // add error handling to taste
    std::copy(*pbuf, temp.begin(), temp.end());
}
```

Comment: `std::copy` please

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The std::copy equivalent is `std::copy( std::back_inserter(output), buffer, buffer+bufsiz)` (and the cast is not explicit).  Personally I find the for-loop easier to read, and I don't see any advantage to std::copy.  YMMV.  (I also didn't have to look up the spec for the for loop.)

Comment: Type safety. Never write `memcpy`! Also that's not the equivalent; your `memcpy` doesn't "insert", it just overwrites, so that's all your `std::copy` needs to do

Comment: Also `*pbufsiz` in your example won't compile

Comment: Oh I see!  You are referring to the memcpy in the aside, not the for-loop in the main part of the answer.  I feel a lot less strongly about that.  (And `memcpy(pbuf, &temp[0], *pbufsiz)` will complile, but not work well!)

Comment: It will now you snuck a `*` in ;)

Comment: Yeah much nicer now ;)